# Is there a way to get a list of all the words in the solr spellcheck index?

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I'm using Solr's SpellCheckComponent with IndexBasedSpellChecker.  Wondering if there's a way to get an output of all the words in the dictionary.

Might help us catch some of the misspellings on our site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is. IndexBasedSpellChecker, according to the [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking): "The IndexBasedSpellChecker uses a Solr index as the basis for a parallel index used for spell checking. It requires defining a field as the basis for the index terms "

So it just uses one field you choose from the index. To enumerate all terms on a field you use the [Terms component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component) and you set *terms.fl* to that field. If you have lots of terms, you could play do some scrolling with *terms.lower*, *terms.limit* and *terms.upper* to get the info in multiple calls.